# Why does the dereference operator have lower precedence than the dot operator?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, operator-precedence, dereference

In C, why does the dereference operator have lower precedence than the operator? This doesn't really make sense to me, because this:

```c
(*p).abc = 123
```

could become this:

```c
*p.abc = 123
```

which would render this not needed:

```c
p->abc = 123
```

Is there some problem with setting the dereference operator to a higher precedence than the dot operator?

Comment: What happens when `p.abc` is a pointer? How do you dereference it?

Comment: Possibly historical reasons. `(*p).abc` used to mean something very different from `p->abc`. Can't find a link to the story behind it now though.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica -- Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Well, you'd have to write `*(p.abc)`, that's all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I wonder if historically, there wasn't really full support for expressions of type `struct foo`.  After all, there wasn't much that one could do to them; none of the arithmetic or logical operators make sense, and historically you couldn't even assign them.  So it may have been that you actually couldn't dereference an expression of type `struct foo *`; you could *only* apply the `->` operator.  The idea of `->` as equivalent to `*` followed by `.` may have only come about later, after support for dereferencing `struct foo *` was added.

Comment: @NateEldredge - Not really all, no. That'd get ugly too. But I don't really see an intuitive syntactic sugar for it. I can totally see language designers going the `(*p).abc` route simply because they already had an intuitive syntactic sugar in the form of `p->abc`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, `p->abc` didn't use to be exact syntactic sugar for `(*p).abc`. The old C compiler would require that p in `(*p).abc` (or more specifically the `*p` subexpression) be a pointer (any pointer) whereas the `p` in `p->abc` could be any scalar (e.g., 42) and it would be coerced into a pointer appropriately offsetted, casted to `typeof(.abc)*` (member names used to be globals) and dereferenced. Either form could be used to do coercions (very useful because prehistoric C didn't have casts) but the dot form additionally required lvalueness in its left argument.

Comment: I always questioned the validity of the `->` operator. If any syntactic sugar should be created, there should be a `.*` operator that does the opposite of `->`; it would de-reference the right side expression.  Therefore, `person->skills`, `*(person.skills)`, and `person.skills->weapons` becomes `*person.skills`, `person.*skills`, and `person.*skills.weapons` respectively.  It's more clear and consistent because a name  or parenthetical is always dereferenced by a star just to its immediate left.